# CQL SELECT fails with prepareStatement

Tags: select, cassandra, prepared-statement, cql, cassandra-jdbc

In my sample app following snippet works fine.

```
SELECT_CQL = "SELECT * FROM " + STREAM_NAME_IN_CASSANDRA + " WHERE '" + CONTEXT_ID_COLUMN + "'=?";
Connection connection = getConnection();
statement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_CQL);
statement.setString(1, "123");
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

But when I try to add another parameter to the where clause query returns nothing!!

```
SELECT_CQL = "SELECT * FROM " + STREAM_NAME_IN_CASSANDRA + " WHERE '" + CONTEXT_ID_COLUMN + "'=? AND '"+TIMESTAMP_COLUMN+"'=?";
Connection connection = getConnection();
statement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_CQL);
statement.setString(1, "123");
statement.setString(2, "1390996577514");
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

When I try the exact query within cqlsh terminal, it works fine.

Comment: bigint, thanks for pointing out this..solved my issue by using, statement.setLong(2, 1390996577514L);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
statement.setString(2, "1390996577514");
```

Double-check the datatype of your `TIMESTAMP_COLUMN` and make sure that it's a string.  Otherwise you'll need to use the appropriate "set" method. Ex:

```
statement.setLong(2, 1390996577514L);
```